# Entity framework initialization cache

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is something which i never found an answer to. We typically have to create a couple of instances of a DbContext at any given time does this means that the DbContext will have to validate all the entities/mappings again and again or does the validation happen only once for a given process/app domain?

If it happens every time, is there anyway we can force it to cache the model definition (POCOS)?

Comment: This should happen only when you start your AppDomain not when you create a new instance of your context. Otherwise the performance will be terrible

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Each time you run the app the default Database Initalizer Strategie  (`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`) run, and compare between the Database and the model.

The same behavior is for the other Database Initalizer types.

If you are confident that the model fits the database status

You can earn performance and charging time by setting the DbInitalizer to null:

```
 Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not really what I asked. That's actually what I do every-time, as well as disabling migrations and such, but the problem goes beyond that. We might use fluent or attributes to define what the model looks like and I am guessing the EF checks that model to see if it valid even if it is not touching the real underlying database and that's what I really want to know. Does this model validation (pocos) happens every time? Once again thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ahh. But why is it bothering you? What do you care?

Comment: well there might be a performance penalty there, even if it still a small one. If the structure of the model does not change while a process is running I'm just wondering why the structure of the model itself isnt cached.